# Drywood Termite repellent (external)

Tags: termite

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vM0bF.jpg)][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vM0bF.jpg)If the source of drywood termites is a second floor sliding glass door (swarming from an external unknown outdoor source), is there a good method / process to repel drywood termite?

I would like to apply a repellent to the aluminum tracks of a sliding glass door.

Two professionals have come by and offered tenting.

[image]
[image]

Comment: I presume you mean that they have chewed through the wood framing around the door, not that they're coming through the door itself.

Comment: @Freeman They were observed originating from a wall shared between to condo owners.

Answer (score 1):

There are various wood treatment products that will help prevent termites from chewing on it and setting up a homestead. Many contain *copper napthenate*, which soaks into the wood when brushed or sprayed on. You asked how to "repel" them, and this works on wood. If you are looking to repel them some other way, can't really comment unless you more fully describe what it is that you want to do.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I would like to apply a repellent to the metal (aluminum?) tracks of a sliding glass door.   Any [examples](https://www.amazon.com/Tenino-Copper-Naphthenate-metal-Preservative/dp/B0147OQQ84) of successes are always appreciated.